# Wordpress Learndash LMS with custom theme?

Tags: wordpress

Hi I wanted to ask a quick question, I`m about to get a project form a client who wants to use the **Learndash LMS** but he also wants to make a custom theme and not use the premium wp & learndash themes.. I just wanted to have an opinion from you guys is that recommended ? and does **Learndash LMS** require any "special" development for the theme or it will work on any theme including custom made themes.

Thank you for your time even if I dont know if this is the right place to ask these type of questions.

Comment: Cool about the question whether Learndash creates special theme requirements. Try to avoid "opinion" questions. The information about the client need isn't required. "Does Learndash LMS require any special development for a theme?" pretty much covers it. Is there a tag for Learndash?

Comment: @DouglasLovell Neither is your reply if you dont have any answer for my subject,
and there is no tag for Learndash and I cant create a new one since I'm new here. Anyway thanks for your "opinion".

Comment: Sorry. That was my poor attempt at helping to improve first time questions. Hope you aren't discuoraged from trying SO again in the future. If you figured-out the answer, you can answer your own question.

Comment: @james, it doesn't matter if you use special theme that support learndash or you create custom theme, so my answer for you is yes, you can use your custom theme and can do the Learndash integration without touching plugin by overriding the template, but for that you need to have core knowledge of learndash to implement the functions.